# Is there an adjective for "Made of Air"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I was trying to think up a name for an ability in a fantasy game which conjures up a shield made of air around oneself, like ____ Shield (analogous to "Earthen Shield", for example). I tried google and came up empty.
The Idea is that strong wind contained in a spherical shape surrounds the user and diverts anything that touches it.

Comment: Since it's a fantasy game and cars are probably not a thing, "Wind Shield" should work.... :-)

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it is urban fantasy, which would make "Wind Shield" sound strange.

Comment: I think you may need to add more details. "Air" is what surrounds us. If you can describe what would make this "conjured shield" distinct from the rest of all the air that naturally occurs, maybe there's a better adjective.

Comment: It's a weird concept, so there's no reason to expect current natural language to have a short way of referring to it. But maybe a ***gaseous** shield*.

Comment: @Kurolong maybe the windshields of your cars are actually magic Wind Shields?  ;-)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with "Air Shield".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of fantasy, a somewhat poetic phrase would be an [***ethereal***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ethereal) **shield**.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1a** : of or relating to the regions beyond the earth
> **b** : CELESTIAL, HEAVENLY
> **c** : UNWORLDLY, SPIRITUAL
> **2a** : lacking material substance : IMMATERIAL, INTANGIBLE
> **c** : suggesting the heavens or heaven

In particular association with "air" would be sense 2a.

---

In actual fantasy games, I've also heard the term **spirit shield**, which is implied as a synonym in the above.

Answer (score 2):

How about **airy** ...
We do say *wooden, earthen, golden*, etc., but we also say *silvery, coppery, brassy, glassy, irony* and not *silveren, copperen,* etc.

> **airy**
>   ADJECTIVE
>    Delicate, as though filled with or made of air.
>   ‘airy clouds’

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/airy)

Comment: I would probably say "silver shield" before "silvery shield".

Comment: @Ian Those are different things, though. I would assume a silver shield to be made of silver, whereas I would assume a silvery shield to _not_ be made of silver, but of something that resembles silver.

Comment: According to the definition above, **airy** could mean "made of air".

Comment: Shakespeare, 'toujours lui':
The poet's eye, in fine frenzy rolling, 
Doth glance from heaven to earth, from earth to heaven; 
And as imagination bodies forth 
The forms of things unknown, the poet's pen
Turns them to shapes and gives to airy nothing 
A local habitation and a name. (A Midsummer Night's Dream: Act V, scene 1, line 1846)

Answer (score 0):

Aerial would be the best fit with the naming convention you have so far, but if you're looking for more flourish, zephyric or tornadic could apply.